# Android configuration in meta-data or in properties file?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm writing a library that is used by developers and I have a configuration items like `apiKey`, `environment` and others. I want to developer to set these values, my first thought was using Java Properties file that I load in the Application class, but I've seen Google Play and Google Map SDK ask the developers to add their apiKey in meta-data tag in Android Manifest. What is the recommended way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recommended android way to let the user define values for your library
from the application module is through meta-tags

it is as easy as using this code on the android-manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.yourproject.apikey" android:value="apikey"/>
```

and you can get these values from your library like this

```
try {
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    Bundle bundle = applicationInfo.metaData;
    String apiKey = bundle.getString("com.yourproject.apikey");
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    //Resolve error for not existing meta-tag, inform the developer about adding his api key
}
```

The main benefits of this approach are

1) That you can let the user define different values per device type e.g. phone, tablet or sdk-version
(this may not be applicable for your case but it's a good point for sure)

2) You can add complex data as the value in your meta-tag,
and you can use this if you want to add a string-array with all the value that you want to declare.

3) Since meta-tags are basically a bundle it is easier for you to

- Read these values on your library code.
- Have default values if the user has not declared the required
  meta-tags.

(I believe that parsing properties from assets requires more code without any great advantage)

4) You can also add configuration meta-tags for activities,providers and broadcastreceiver on your AndroidManifest.

5) Also I suppose that it is easier to request for the consumers of your library to add a few meta info on his Android Manifest, than adding a properties file on their assets folder.And i believe that this is the main reason Many known libraries use this approach like google-play-service, google-maps, crash reporting libraries and many libraries that provide user analytic.

Good Luck

Answer (score 3):

It´s seems that using meta-data tag is the Android way to achieve this, although I can´t find any official documentation to argue why.

Using meta-data you can define you property value using a resource instead of a static value, this way you can get different values for the same property based on the resources qualifier. This is very useful if your property needs internalization.

Ex:

```
<meta-data android:value="foo.bar" android:name="@string/hello" />
```

Answer (score 0):

is easy using this 
`<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="API_KEY"/>`